# SoX Windows 7 64-Bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, troubleshooting, sox

Is there a version of SoX that is compatible with 64-Bit Windows 7?  Whenever i try to run "sox.exe" (or any other program in 14.4.0), all that happens is that a command prompt window opens and closes, almost simultaneously.  I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: This is normal for any program that is designed primarily for command-line use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SoX is not meant to be run by double-clicking on it in Explorer. Open a command prompt and pass the executable all appropriate arguments.

```
> sox.exe infile.wav outfile.mp3
```